# Why is my span not showing in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot get this span class `.time-name` shown up on IE 9, even with content mode set to IE Edge.

It gets displayed on Firefox and Google independent of any JS library or other CSS classes defined here.

I already have this meta tag in: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` and am using Bootstrap.

Can anyone help me?

```css
.time-count-container {
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.time-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -ms-border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.time-box-inner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.time-number {
  font-size: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-top: 15%;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  -ms-transition: all .25s;
  -o-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.time-number .digit {
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.time-name {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="time_countdown" class="time-count-container">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="time-box">
      <div class="time-box-inner dash days_dash animated" data-animation="rollIn" data-animation-delay="300">
        <span class="time-number">
          <span class="digit">0</span>
          <span class="digit">0</span>
          <span class="digit">0</span>
        </span>
        <span class="time-name">Days</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="time-box">
      <div class="time-box-inner dash hours_dash animated" data-animation="rollIn" data-animation-delay="600">
        <span class="time-number">
          <span class="digit">0</span>
          <span class="digit">0</span>
        </span>
        <span class="time-name">Hours</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="time-box">
      <div class="time-box-inner dash minutes_dash animated" data-animation="rollIn" data-animation-delay="900">
        <span class="time-number">
          <span class="digit">0</span>
          <span class="digit">0</span>
        </span>
        <span class="time-name">Minutes</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="time-box">
      <div class="time-box-inner dash seconds_dash animated" data-animation="rollIn" data-animation-delay="1200">
        <span class="time-number">
          <span class="digit">0</span>
          <span class="digit">0</span>
        </span>
        <span class="time-name">Seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qhpuxddx/1/

```
.time-name {
  position: relative; <----- add this
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: It works now! Thanks for the solution. I tried many other things already but did not think of this.